How to use Webpack or other bundler to build chrome extensions?
I would like to use node modules in my extension, but in the final version this folder would be collected into a single js file, and other js files would also be minified into a single file. I would also like to be able to load an unbuilt version into chrome to check how it works before loading the built version. Is this possible? I tried asking ChatGPT, but he gave me a structure in which node modules is located outside both the original and built versions:
/project
  ├── /extension
  │   ├── popup.html
  │   ├── popup.js
  │   └── ...
  ├── /dist
  ├── /node_modules
  ├── package.json
  └── webpack.config.js     

As I understand it, the unbundled version in the "extension" folder will not work in the browser if it uses something from node modules.
And how should this be done correctly? Maybe I'm wrong, and it is generally not customary to run an unbuilt version in the browser for testing?
And if, for example, the extension uses Vue, then it is necessary to use Vite for assembly instead of Webpack?

Find an existing boilerplate for chrome extension development and use it. In short, it creates a usable extension in dist folder, which you can load in unpacked mode on chrome://extensions page, then the bundler will watch the changes in the source code and recompile the necessary parts automatically.
